# python HTTPSConnection to curl auto convertion

Tags: python, curl

I m writing a python client/module to offer support for python users supporting a non-python server that is controled by another group of developers and is written in node.js

The server has a lot of capabilities including https, websockets, 3 authentication modes etc.

My problem is their time bugdet they can offer to help is very limited, and when some of my request fail, no one on the other speaks python or has time to learn, so they cannot check why this happens. From my side I am mainly using `http.client`'s `HTTPSConnection` e.g. in the simplest example

```
c = HTTPSConnection(self.credentials['host'])
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % self.credentials['auth']}
c.request('GET', path, headers=headers)
```

(also PUT to send data etc)
Is there any general way to print the request's `curl` equivalent so that I can send them
some non-python code I can complain does not work for me?
I can easily think how to do this by hand and have seen questions that asks specifics of that, however I would like a general, automatic way,  like `request_to_curl(HTTPSConnection.request)` or something